# How do I fix noise in render? UPDATE

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am fairly new to blender but I keep running into the same problem when using cycles. The noise is unbearable and I can't seem to find the reason. I followed every advice I could find through google and it all seems to make it worse. If you are interested I have a completed render that I tried to create. [image: The Horrible Render]

If anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful.

UPDATE:
I would like to start by saying thank you for the links and the advice. I have been spending my time just messing around with blender settings and got the noise to clear using a combination of denoising and turning off refractive caustics. I'm not sure how the disabling of refractive caustics helped, but oh well. I have been able to drastically improve the quality of the image, but I would say that it still looks poor quality, but I think I'll look for other questions regarding this issue first. Here is what the finished product looks: [image: Finished Render]

Comment: You are using window as a light **Portal**, right? It will be extremely difficult to trace the light path since it is not directly go through the window. Go search "Blender Portal light" should help your scene a lot

Comment: Please help others help you, what are your render settings? Light path settings, samples, ect. The more information you share the more others can help. Some helpful questions to read: [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles) and [How To Reduce Noise In Cycles Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-reduce-noise-in-cycles-render) and [Noise in Cycles Interior Scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62736/noise-in-cycles-interior-scene)

Comment: By "every advice" what do you mean?  What have you tried already?  I'm assuming you've already tried increasing the sample count.  What have you set it to?